# SyntaxError: Unexpected token true in html generated by ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why I am getting this error: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token true** in line

```
$('#atp_13').append("<a data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/clots/test/unjoin"><i class='icon-check clot-unfollow-icon'></i></a>)");
```

i m generating this using

```
$('#<%= "atp_#{@atp.id}" %>').append("<%= link_to unjoin_atp_path(@atp), :method => :delete, remote: true do %><i class='icon-check clot-unfollow-icon'></i><% end %>)");
```

Comment: Fix the quotes. Use `"` for the class in `<i class="...">` and use `'` for the string in `.append('...')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#atp_<%=@atp.id %>").append("<%= escape_javascript(link_to unjoin_atp_path(@atp), :method => :delete, remote: true do %><i class='icon-check clot-unfollow-icon'></i><% end %>)");
```

escape_javascript is used to escape the rails helper methods to be replaced in the page.

You can move the link_to tag to a partial file to make it clean, and you can call the partial name in the js.erb file.

```
$("#atp_<%=@atp.id %>").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'partial_name') ) %>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the `"` character is not properly escaped

```
"<a data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/clots/test/unjoin"><i class='icon-check clot-unfollow-icon'></i></a>)"
```

vs.

```
"<a data-remote=\"true\" rel=\"nofollow\" data-method=\"delete\" href=\"/clots/test/unjoin\"><i class='icon-check clot-unfollow-icon'></i></a>)"
```

Notice the colour of true in both examples. The first example is like declaring a variable this way:

```
var a = "something is "true;
```